# Tabbed content -

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nmu2F/2/

It seems to work, however, the content is on the same line as the navigation. What is the correct way to get the content to sit below it?

```
ul.tabs li {
    float:left;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    display:block;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
li.active a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nmu2F/4/)

CSS:

```
.tabContainer {
    clear:both;
}
```